# How to refresh the page when custom plugin is saved?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-cms

I have created a website using Django cms. When I save the custom plugin the template is not rendered. But it is rendered when I refresh the page.

So, how to refresh the page while saving the django cms custom plugin or any other way to render the template when the plugin is saved. But the content is saved in the admin side. I am not able to see the content in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use ajax here. This is a very vague code on how you should go about it. but hope it helps.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.save-plugin-button-id').click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
           url: url_which_saves_plugin,
           method: 'GET',
           data:{},#add data required if any or leave blank
           success: function(data){
                #You might want to stylize your data here. 
                $("#update-content-div-id").append(JSON.stringify(data));
           }
       })


       })
    })        
</script>
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. But, it won't work. I just want to know if anything can be done by python code in the cms_plugins.py file. This is like overriding the django system template.